# i have checked out answers but couldn't solve the issue 'expected an indented block'

Tags: python-3.x

i have a code like this and i get an error "expected an indented block"
 event = Events(int(splitted[0]), int(splitted[1]), int(splitted[2]), int(splitted[3]),splitted[4].lower()) for this line. I'm new to python so can't figure out what is really going on. please

```
 class Events:          ## arama ve sms classı (user arama ya da sms oluşturduğunda listeye girecek olan objeler buradan üretilecek)
        callduration = 0
        def __init__(self, PhoneNo, Year, Month, Day, Type):
            self.PhoneNo = PhoneNo
            self.Year = Year
            self.Month = Month
            self.Day = Day
            self.Type = Type
    class User:
        EventsList = []   ## event objelerinin listede tutulması
        def __init__(self, PhoneNo, FName, LName):   ## user classından obje üretmek için construction
            self.PhoneNo = PhoneNo
            self.FName = FName
            self.LName = LName
            self.Credit = 100
            self.Smscounter = 0

        def Add(self):   ## Add fonksiyonu
            print("Add Event with comma for example : PhoneNo,Year,Month,Day,Type(SMS OR CALLING)")
            print("PhoneNo,Year,Month,Day,Type(SMS OR CALLING)")
            eventInput = input()
            splitted = eventInput.split(",")   ## Virgüllerin Split işlemi arraya atılması

            if len(splitted) == 5:
                try:

                event = Events(int(splitted[0]), int(splitted[1]), int(splitted[2]), int(splitted[3]),splitted[4].lower())
                if event.Type == "sms":   ## SMS kontrolü
                    if(self.Credit != 0):
                        self.Credit = self.Credit - 1  ## Credittten Düşme
                    self.Smscounter = self.Smscounter + 1
                    print("\n ~~~~~~Call/Sms Added~~~~~ \n")
                    self.EventsList.append(event)

                elif event.Type == "call":  ## Arama Kontrolü
                    print("Call duration in minute ?")
                    duration = input()
                    event.callduration = int(duration)   ## Arama dakikası inputu alma
                    print("\n ~~~~~~Call/Sms Added~~~~~ \n")
                    self.EventsList.append(event)
            else:
                print("Wrong Input!")


                    except Exception:
                        print("Wrong Input")

                    else:
                        print("Wrong Input!")
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct version of your code:

```
class Events:  ## arama ve sms classı (user arama ya da sms oluşturduğunda listeye girecek olan objeler buradan üretilecek)
    callduration = 0

    def __init__(self, PhoneNo, Year, Month, Day, Type):
        self.PhoneNo = PhoneNo
        self.Year = Year
        self.Month = Month
        self.Day = Day
        self.Type = Type


class User:
    EventsList = []  ## event objelerinin listede tutulması

    def __init__(self, PhoneNo, FName, LName):  ## user classından obje üretmek için construction
        self.PhoneNo = PhoneNo
        self.FName = FName
        self.LName = LName
        self.Credit = 100
        self.Smscounter = 0

    def Add(self):  ## Add fonksiyonu
        print("Add Event with comma for example : PhoneNo,Year,Month,Day,Type(SMS OR CALLING)")
        print("PhoneNo,Year,Month,Day,Type(SMS OR CALLING)")
        eventInput = input()
        splitted = eventInput.split(",")  ## Virgüllerin Split işlemi arraya atılması

        if len(splitted) == 5:
            try:
                event = Events(int(splitted[0]), int(splitted[1]), int(splitted[2]), int(splitted[3]), splitted[4].lower())
                if event.Type == "sms":  ## SMS kontrolü
                    if (self.Credit != 0):
                        self.Credit = self.Credit - 1  ## Credittten Düşme
                    self.Smscounter = self.Smscounter + 1
                    print("\n ~~~~~~Call/Sms Added~~~~~ \n")
                    self.EventsList.append(event)

                elif event.Type == "call":  ## Arama Kontrolü
                    print("Call duration in minute ?")
                    duration = input()
                    event.callduration = int(duration)  ## Arama dakikası inputu alma
                    print("\n ~~~~~~Call/Sms Added~~~~~ \n")
                    self.EventsList.append(event)
            except Exception:
                print("Wrong Input")

            else:
                print("Wrong Input!")

        else:
            print("Wrong Input!")
```

please pay attention to the editing that i made in your code. couple of things to remember:
you can't have an outer scope between a try/except block. that is like breaking their connection. 
print statements like any other sub-scope code, must be indented if they are going to be part of a scope.